# Not able to unsign apk file using RE-sign.jar

Tags: eclipse, robotium

For automating apk file I need this but not through cmd but through robotium.re-sign.jar

When I was dropping an apk file on re-sign.jar file it gives an Error something like - {ERROR : Cannot run program "D:\SDK\SDK/tools/zipalign": Create process error = 2,The system cannot find the file specified}

Answer (score 0):

For create a apk for Google Play Publish, look this tutorial, you have to solve this problem is : https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/861/how-to-sign-and-align-your-android-app-apk

Comment: Sir can you please, expalin for without using cmd

Comment: Right-click your project in Eclipse > Chose Android Tool > Export Signed Application Package...
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

re-sign.jar search for zipalign in the old path(tool). However, it is in build-tool. Try to set ANDROID_HOME to the root of SDK which contain both tool and build-tool folders.